How to create a campaign using API in MailerLite?
I'm trying to create a campaign in MailerLite through the API using PHP, but I'm getting a 422 Unprocessable Entity error. It looks like the data I'm sending to the server is incorrect, but I followed the documentation.
Here is the data I'm sending to the server:
$data = array(
        'name' => "campagne11",
        'type' => "regular",
        'emails' => array(
            'subject'=>"premier test",
            'from_name' => "maxime",
            'from' => "escargot@zinzinzin.online",
            'text_block' =>"Hello, ceci est un premier mail de test. A plus!"
        ),
        'groups' => array('id'=>120228236649039542),
        
    );



emails..text_block is not present, you have to use emails..content
